# How can I define Model ViewSet for contact form that sends email in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, contact-form

I have a APIView for a contact that takes input data from user and send it to mail:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class ContactView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = ContactSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            data = serializer_class.validated_data
            name = data.get('name')
            email = data.get('email')
            message = data.get('message')

            send_mail('Contact Form Mail from ' + name, message, email, ['bibekjoshi34@gmail.com'],)

            return Response({"success":"sent"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error":"failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('contactapi', views.ContactView.as_view()),
]
```

**Question:**

How can I do it using DRF ModelViewset? This below code isn't working.

```
class CustomerContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['post']

    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer_class = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            data = serializer_class.validated_data
            full_name = data.get('full_name')
            email = data.get('email')
            phone_no = data.get('phone_no')
            message = data.get('message')

            send_mail('Mail From' + full_name, phone_no, message, email, ['bibekjoshi34@gmail.com'],)

            return Response({"success":"sent"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error":"failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What is the best way to make contact-form: that stores data in database as well as sends to the admin mail: --------> For Production Level?

Comment: what error are coming when hit this API? and there are issue with your post function

Comment: I got it ! I need to override the create method. Post -----> Create and its Working

Comment: good to hear if you want to all functionality you can use ModelViewSet or if you want to add extra functionality in those method you can override them as you want